# Magento 2 How to modify query for list of parent products which have no attribute but child have that attributes?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-attribute

I am working on to get all the products that have attributes match.
My current code is

```
$categoryProducts1 = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$categoryProducts1->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$categoryProducts1->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('from' => 0, 'to' => 2500));
echo $categoryProducts1->count();
echo "<br>";
echo $categoryProducts1->getSelect()->__toString();
echo "<br>";
foreach ($categoryProducts1 as $_pro) {
    echo $_pro->getId().' === '.$_pro->getName();
    echo "<br>";
}
```

So here I get only simple products and configureable child products but not the configurable parent one products because the parent product has price 0. So, In this case, I need to display that configurable product too. So I need simple products and configurable parent products only.

So please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you filtering for the price, this table will be helpful for you: `catalog_product_index_price`. This is a default Mage2 table that has reindexed data about prices of all products and takes into account catalog product rules and special prices for different customer groups.

Also, `catalog_category_product_index_store1` will be helpful for you. You can join it to your collection and filter by `visibility`(don't forget to filter by store).

Comment: thanks, but can you write exact query here. because I do not want custom query. I want just add ore  replace existing code.